# Export area as image in html

Tags: html, css, export

I have an html page with an area designed using css. I'm looking for suggestions if we can export an html area as an image.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "export an html area"??

Comment: can you set up an example in http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think you want to take a screenshot of a particular portion or elements in your web page. If that is the case, it is not possible with just CSS and you need JavaScript. 
Google is doing this in Google+ and a talented developer reverse engineered it and produced http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ . To work in IE you'll need a canvas support library such as http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot using your preferred software. GIMP is free and capable.

If that software gave you a full screen screenshot (rather then a region), use an image editor to crop it.

Answer (score 0):

http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/

http://www.websitescreenshots.com/

http://www.princexml.com/

http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/

http://linkpeek.com/